# Cannot read property 'getRelatedTab' of undefined (Console error)

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, visual-composer

I have searched a lot to fix this. but not succeeded find this fix. I'm working with **visual composer 5.4.7** and **Wordpress 4.9.6** i have used Visual composer tabs in a webpage. there it shows the below error and does not shows the dropdown list of main_menu.

> JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed, version 1.4.1 
>   vc-tabs.min.js?x71958&ver=5.0.1:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getRelatedTab' of undefined 
>   at HTMLDocument.changeHandler (vc-tabs.min.js?x71958&ver=5.0.1:1)
>       at HTMLDocument.dispatch (jquery.js?x71958&ver=1.12.4:3)
>       at HTMLDocument.r.handle (jquery.js?x71958&ver=1.12.4:3)
>       at Object.trigger (jquery.js?x71958&ver=1.12.4:3)
>       at Object.a.event.trigger (jquery-migrate.min.js?x71958&ver=1.4.1:2)
>       at HTMLDivElement. (jquery.js?x71958&ver=1.12.4:3)
>       at Function.each (jquery.js?x71958&ver=1.12.4:2)
>       at a.fn.init.each (jquery.js?x71958&ver=1.12.4:2)
>       at a.fn.init.trigger (jquery.js?x71958&ver=1.12.4:3)
>       at a.fn.init.t.fn.(/beta/shared-hosting/anonymous function) [as hide] (http://tech.co.uk/beta/wp-content/plugins/wordpress-popup/assets/js/front.min.js?x71958&ver=1.1:2:14154)

All the other pages which are not using visual composer working pretty good with nav_menu dropdown and responsiveness.

I am not getting this how to get rid of these errors. please help me out of this.

Comment: Please, provide your code.

Comment: @htshame http://saremcotech.co.uk/beta/shared-hosting/
http://saremcotech.co.uk/beta/about-us/
you can visit these 2 pages. one which has VC tabs do not showing the dropdown at WEBHOSTING menu item. but second page is working fine.

Comment: @htshame Thank you man.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just Going to folder/file Manager **websiteData/wp-content/plugins/**  and rename the folder **Wordpress-popup** //add a number at the end. this will deactivate the plugin and this was generating errors for other functionalities.

> (http://tech.co.uk/beta/wp-content/plugins/wordpress-popup/assets/js/front.min.js?x71958&ver=1.1:2:14154)

this is the only plugin which is conflicting with VC_tabs

Thanks

Comment: Thank you for the hint: For me it was a conflict with "Cookie Notice" from dfactory.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an incompatibility with other plugins.

Try to deactivate other plugins until the error is gone.

Known plugins to have issues with Visual Composer tabs:

- [Cookie Notice for GDPR](https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/cookie-notice/)
- [Hustle – Pop-Ups, Slide-ins and Email Opt-ins](https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-popup/)
- [WP Fastest Cache](https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-fastest-cache/) (not possible to clear the cache through admin bar)

Comment: I've created a ticket at WPBakery for this. #68220